# how to show row values in column?

Tags: oracle-11g

i have a database sample that looks like this:-

[image]

as you can see my student master id is repeated. i want student master id to appear only once (in one row) can corresponding roll numbers to appear in columns. like this:-

[image]

Comment: Did you try something on your own?

Comment: i tried pivot but it is not working as it only accepts aggregate query like count, min,max,avg which is not required in this case.

Comment: Although it is not required you can use min or max with a pivot solution